# Chinese input does not work in Chrome (Ubuntu 23.04)

Tags: google-chrome, ibus, fcitx

I have just installed Ubuntu 23.04 and found Chinese input does not work in Chrome.  It does work on other applications, e.g. Firefox or gedit. Although the current status is set to "中" in the IME tray icon, I still cannot enter Chinese in Chrome.

I have not tried Chromium, but I tried to use Fcitx5 instead of the default ibus, to no avail.

It could be because Chrome is a "qt" application, but I cannot verify that, and google search results are mostly about older version of Ubuntu, and no effective clue is found.

Comment: Same issue and not found a working solution yet.

Comment: And it works in global search panel(or launcher), weird.

Comment: BTW, I am now using Microsoft Edge which uses chrome core. Chinese IME works well in Edge.